# Microsoft Store showing old product license

Tags: windows-10, product-key, oem, licensing, volume-license

I had Windows 10 Pro volume license. After the first Windows setup, that license associated the motherboard. When I setup Windows again it is activating automatic. I do not want it. Recently, I found Windows 10 Home Retail product license, that is never used. It is working but Microsoft Store doesn't show, only showing past usage. Any product license never linked to any Microsoft account. I mean I want fresh start, I do not want to see past usage without Microsoft Store's Hide option.

[image]

Comment: When you installed it did you modify the installation media to be a Retail disk?  If you didn’t you installed Windows 10 Home. Now you can manually upgrade to Windows 10 or if it’s a new installation just reinstall Windows 10 by changing the ISO to prompt you to select the edition you want to install

Comment: If you don’t believe the **answer** to the duplicate answers your question, you will need to edit your question, to clarify what your question is exactly.